# Initialize RabbitMQ metrics for Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, metrics

I am unsuccessfully trying to use [RabbitMQ metrics support for Java](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2016/11/30/metrics-support-in-rabbitmq-java-client-4-0/).

My objective is to get some messaging statistics into my Java program. When testing I use a RabbitMQ instance at *localhost*, and I have put some test data into a test queue on a test virtual host using the RabbitMQ web interface.

My non-working code is:

```java
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(host); // localhost
    connectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    connectionFactory.setPort(port); // 5672
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);

    StandardMetricsCollector metrics = new StandardMetricsCollector();
    connectionFactory.setMetricsCollector(metrics);
```

It seems like `metrics` is **not properly initialized**:

- Metrics have the default value 0
- Within `metrics` there are properties called `initialized` set to *false* (for instance `metrics.getPublishedMessages().m1Rate.initialized`)

So, it seems I am missing something important here despite trying to follow the official [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#metrics).

---

As a workaround, I'm currently using [HTTP requests to the API](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) to get some basic messaging statistics, but the API is very limited.

Comment: It can be noted that for diagnostic purposes there is a method in the API (/api/aliveness-test/vhost) that performs a healthcheck by declaring a test queue, then publishes and consumes a message.